# Facebook sharer on mobile

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

So I'm trying to make a share button on a webapp. I tried to use:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://google.com/&p[images][0]=&p[title]=Foobar&p[summary]=Hello%20world
```

It works fine here on my laptop. However, if I open the exact same url on my Android phone, I get redirected to:

```
https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://google.com/&p[images][0]=&p[title]=Foobar&p[summary]=Hello%20world
```

Which doesn't work. Am I missing something here? Should I use another API? I want to post a dynamic message with a link.

Comment: try using the the javascript sdk and the fb dialog share https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/